# Different column length data in a single table in mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have come across a project that enables the user to generate the form himself. Generating the form using jQuery is achievable. What comes next is the real problem which is how to store those unexpected data into one table? 
It means that every time the data comes from the page is going to be different from the others but should be saved in the same table.
How can I have a table that deals with such data?

Comment: Take a (cautious) look at EAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one lookup table containing the data types and a second table containing the values contained into the form. Something like that:

```
TableLkp: id, description
TableValues: id, user_id, lkp_id, value
```

Or save those data in a nosql database